# What is the word for a time period between two interactions

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a word that describes the period or artificial interval  between two interactions.

Let's say: I need to check my emails often, but they don't change every second and I don't want to sit in front of the computer all day. So I create myself an artificial interval, say 1 hour, and check the mail 24 times a day.

"I check my emails 24 times a day, because my ... is 1 hour."

Comment: Customer support staff sometimes quote a **response time**- the time that it takes to respond to a message from the user. Obviously, you can't always respond immediately so the time from reading to replying might need to be factored in.

Comment: Frankly, I think the best word is probably just "interval".  I wouldn't phrase it the way your sentence is phrased, though; I would say something like "I check my email at intervals of one hour."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a specific, single word for your usage,  but easy possibilities are

> **checking interval**
>   **checking time**
>   **checking period**

You could also say

> I check my emails 24 times a day, because I check my emails every hour.

Answer (score 2):

A recurring cycle is a period. Perhaps, you can use the word 'period' or'periodicity' for your email need. You could then say:

I check my emails on a periodic cycle of 30 minutes. Sounds a little heavy but saves some extra typing.